# How to use Javascript to make this button do whatever it does when the mouse hovers over it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, facebook, dom-events

This is the privacy button that shows on your status updates on your Facebook wall.

[image]

When you click on that icon, you get these options.

[image]

I am trying to make a Greasemonkey script to automatically click on one of those selections. My script works fine, with the only caveat being that I have to hover my mouse over that icon before running the script, or else it won't work. I don't even have to actually open the dialog by clicking on it, I just have to move my mouse over the [image] icon.

So I'm trying to find a way to use Javascript to hover the mouse over that icon, or click on it, so that I don't have to manually do it. I've tried the `.click()` and `.trigger()` methods, but they don't seem to be of any help here.

I think this is the code for the button.

```
<a rel="toggle" data-tooltip="Your friends; Except: Restricted" data-length="30"
data-label="" aria-haspopup="1" href="#" ajaxify="/ajax/timeline/show_story_options.php?profile_id=707236195&amp;story_fbid=10150597306856196&amp;story_row_time=1331626509&amp;permalink=1&amp;story_div_id=stream_story_4f6620b08c1851b03797773&amp;story_dom_id=stream_story_4f6620b08c1851b03797773&amp;small_icon=1"
role="button" class="uiSelectorButton uiButton uiButtonSuppressed uiButtonNoText"
tooltip-alignh="right" title="" data-hover="tooltip" id="js_1"><i class="mrs defaultIcon customimg img sp_4uwvrx sx_bff9bf"></i><span class="uiButtonText"></span></a>
```

I tried using jQuery to get the url specified in the ajaxify tag, because I noticed that that's one of the things that happens when I hover my mouse over the button. Even though I can successfully GET the page, it doesn't seem to make any difference either.

How can I use Javascript to make this button do whatever it does when I manually hover my mouse over it?

Comment: Why did someone vote to close? What's wrong with this question?

Comment: It wasn't me, but I think because it's too localized and wont be useful to anyone else.

Comment: I don't think it's too localized, since everyone is on Facebook now!

Answer (score 1):

I think what your after is something like the do click function found int the link below you could mix in with some query.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17241/Capturing-the-Enter-key-to-cause-a-button-click

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a hurry, so I can't in-depth with my answer, but I thought dropping this might be of some help.

There is this module called Selenium that lets you use a browser with javascript to do whatever you want on a webpage.

Guide: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node

Module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver

Another Module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver

I know this is not a direct answer, but hopefully, it comes in handy.